# Is there a specification for whether a position in a web page is a valid position to place a cursor for text editing?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

Recently I've encountered a few situations where I ended up using CSS hacks so that the user would be able to place a cursor for text editing in a previously position in a contenteditable div. My specific situation is close to what I have below:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 4em;
  min-height: 4em;
}

span {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

br:last-of-type {
  display: none;
}

div.hack br:last-of-type {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4em; // This seems to be necessary for the correct vertical alignment of the blinking input cursor
}
```

```html
Using Google Chrome, Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) Can't place the cursor here:
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    <!-- This is an existing implementation. Hopefully someday I'll get to rewrite it. -->
    <span> some hidden text for padding </span>
    <!-- Can't put the cursor here for text input -->
    <br />
  </p>
</div>

But I can here:
<div class="hack" contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    <!-- This is an existing implementation. Hopefully someday I'll get to rewrite it. -->
    <span> some hidden text for padding </span>
    <!-- Can't put the cursor here for text input -->
    <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

My guess is that the issue is that there were no selectable inline elements in the paragraph, so the browser (I'm using Chrome) doesn't let the user place a cursor there. Setting the display style on the `<br/>` tag in the paragraph fixes this, but it feels hacky. This solution is fine for our purposes, but for future reference I'd like to know if there is any kind of specification for determining what is a valid text input position in a contenteditable div. I've done a bit of Googling and didn't find much, though it's possible I just don't know the correct wording for the question.

Side note - The structure of the document is an existing implementation, and I am not currently looking for alternatives for that. In particular, the `<br/>` tag is an implementation detail in a dependency and based on some of their Q&A stuff, that isn't likely to change.

Comment: In order for `contenteditable` to work, there must be some content first. Such as 0 wide space or placeholder.

Comment: In your example both div aren't editable for me, but if I just use `<div contenteditable="true" style="padding:10px;"><p></p></div>` it's good (in Chrome and Firefox) so I'm not sure to understand your problem

Comment: Please provide a [mre] here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, not sure if it works differently for IE or Firefox. Also, I added a Stack Snippet. I wasn't even aware that existed.